# HTML5 Valid Meta Data List?

Tags: html, metadata

I'm an amateur web designer, I want to know about meta data in HTML5, 
Can anybody tell me the complete list of HTML5 valid meta data?

Comment: Take a look over here http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/meta.name.html and here http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/meta.html

Answer (score 3):

In the HTML5 specification, you can visit the section for the [`meta` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-meta-element) to see which values you are allowed to use for the `name` attribute.

You'll find out that HTML5 defines [standard metadata names](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#standard-metadata-names) and that [additional metadata names can be registered](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#other-metadata-names), whereby all additional registrations are listed at [the WHATWG wiki](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions#Registered_Extensions).

**Summary**: You should use only the values for the `name` attribute that are listed at:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#standard-metadata-names
- http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions#Registered_Extensions

---

Metadata can be given in several other ways, too.

For `link`, `a` and `area` elements you may use [**link relationships**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#linkTypes) (part of the HTML5 specification).

For semantic annotation of your content, you may use [**RDFa**](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-lite/) or [**Microdata**](http://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/) with appropriate vocabularies.

For a few simple use cases, you may use [**Microformats**](http://microformats.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Meta data can be specified in many ways, and at different levels. A few sources of meta data:

meta tag - http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/meta.name.html

base tag - http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/base.html

link tag - http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/links.html#linkTypes

microformats - http://microformats.org/wiki/html5

Comment: +1 for microformats, and metadata outside of <meta> tags in general!

Answer (score 0):

The full list of valid values for the `name` attribute of the `meta` element is [this WHATWG wiki page](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions).  If you're talking about generic metadata, HTML5 has a built in extensibility option with [Microdata](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/microdata.html), see [Schema.org](http://schema.org/docs/schemas.html) for some well known structures.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you are trying to ask.

I usually include the following meta data.  I come to these choices based on .netmag reading and websites such as stackoverflow and ccstricks etc..

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

There are many other variations but these work fine for me.